# How can I add a constraint on a denormalized foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

In a SQL Server database, I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship.  Table2 has a column, Table1ID, which is a foreign key.

Now our business rules require us to add a third table, Table3, which will be "in between" the other two tables.  So Table3 will have a Table1ID foreign key, and Table2 will have a Table3ID.  We need to keep the Table1ID in Table2 for backwards compatibility.

How can I ensure that the Table1ID in Table2 always matches the Table1ID for the matching record in Table3?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by defining the foreign key constraint between tables 2 and 3 on both the table3id and the table1id columns.

Comment: If taking @David's approach you may need to add a primary key (or unique) constraint to the Table2.Table3ID column to ensure you don't have multiple Table3ID rows in Table2, but with possibly different Table1ID values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible.  There is no unique constraint on any of these.  Table2 will contain many records with the same Table3ID.  My application will enforce this rule and prevent inserting a record in Table2 with a non-matching Table1ID, but I was hoping there is some way to enforce it in the database.

Comment: Well, that's the usual dilemma. Your application either does or does not enforce integrity, and because of issues like read consistency mechanisms in the database, the app technology almost certainly does not guarantee integrity -- the docs for Ruby on Rails for example specifically state that this is the case. Using the db to enforce integrity requires that you use unique/pk constraints and normalisation, and without those you're not going to get very far I'm afraid.

Comment: That's pretty much what I anticipated, but I thought I'd put it out there to see if there was something I was unaware of.  Thanks for the feedback David and BStateham.